# Azure B2C what is serviceProviderMetadata?

Tags: azure, saml, azure-ad-b2c

I have a setup with Azure B2C as a SAML token issuer and ADFS as SAML IdP.

Every time I try to login a get the following error from B2C (it does not go further to ADFS):

**FatalException**

*The value must not be null or white space. Parameter name: serviceProviderMetadata*

What does it mean in B2C?
Am I missing something in my Azure B2C SAML issuer configuration?
Here is my SignIn policy

```
<RelyingParty>
<DefaultUserJourney ReferenceId="SignUpOrSignInFmdClient" />
<UserJourneyBehaviors>
  <SingleSignOn Scope="Application" />
    <SessionExpiryType>Absolute</SessionExpiryType>
  <SessionExpiryInSeconds>900</SessionExpiryInSeconds>      
</UserJourneyBehaviors>
<TechnicalProfile Id="PolicyProfile">
  <DisplayName>PolicyProfile</DisplayName>
  <Protocol Name="SAML2" />

  <Metadata>
    <Item Key="KeyEncryptionMethod">Rsa15</Item>
    <Item Key="DataEncryptionMethod">Aes256</Item>
    <Item Key="XmlSignatureAlgorithm">Sha256</Item>
  </Metadata>

  <OutputClaims>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="socialIdpUserId" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="IdpUserGroups" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="IdpUserName"/>        
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="identityProvider" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="userPrincipalName" PartnerClaimType="userPrincipalName" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId"/>
  </OutputClaims>

  <SubjectNamingInfo ClaimType="userPrincipalName" Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:persistent" ExcludeAsClaim="false"/>
</TechnicalProfile>
```

Comment: Have you got the PartnerEntity metadata set under the RelyingParty ? This error would suggest that you don't. Are you able to provide an Extract of your policy ?

Comment: I added my RelyingParty configuration from SignUpOrSignIn policy to the question. What is PartnerEntity metadata ? Who is the partner?

Comment: What if partner has no metadata published?

Comment: You will need to add the Service Providers Metadata URL within the PartnerEntity Metadata item. If they do not have a URL then you can put the whole metadata XML within a CDATA element.

Answer (score 0):

This is the SAML data that is fetched and loaded on demand for every service and then cached in a global cache for a configurable duration. You need to add a value for the metadata URL so that it does not return null.

Example:

```
<Item Key="PartnerEntity">https://adfs.example.com/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml&lt;/Item>
```

You will also need to set the PartnerEntity to True to Allow yourself to specify a link to the federation metadata XML file.

Comment: What do you mean to set it to true? Isn't it a string URL value that points to the federation metadata published by an application relying party ?